# Covariance of dice tosses that result in 1 or 2 (fake proof)

Tags: probability, dice, fake-proofs

**Question**: 
Consider n independent tosses of a $k$-sided fair dice. Let $X_i$ be the number of tosses that result in $i$.

What is the covariance $\mathrm{cov}(X_1,X_2)$ of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

---

\begin{align}
\mathrm{cov}(X_1,X_2) = \mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] - \mathbf{E}[X_1]\mathbf{E}[X_2]
\end{align}

I get a different $\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2]$ than the given solution.

**The solution given is**

Let $A_t$ (respectively, $B_t$) be a Bernoulli random variabe that is equal to 1 if and only if the $t$th toss resulted in 1 (respectively, 2). We have **E**$[A_tB_t] = 0$ (since $A_t \neq 0$ implies $B_t \neq 0$)

$$ \mathbf{E}[A_tB_s] = \mathbf{E}[A_t]\mathbf{E}[B_t] = \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k}   \mathrm{for}\  s \neq t.$$

Thus,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] &= \mathbf{E}[(A_1+\cdots + A_n)(B_1+\cdots B_n)]\\
 &=n\mathbf{E}[A_1(B_1+\cdots+B_n)] = n(n-1)\cdot   \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k} \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)}{k^2}
\end{align}

and

---

**My solution that gives slightly off answer**

My approach uses iterated expectations.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2|X2]]
\end{align}
If I had $k$ instead of $k-1$ in the following equation, I would get an answer identical to given solution but if I already know $X_2=x_2$ then dice tosses should be identically distributed among k-1 remaining options, right?
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1|X_2=x_2] = \frac{n-x_2}{k-1} 
\end{align}

Then 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2|X_2] = \frac{n-X_2}{k-1} \cdot X_2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2|X_2]] = \mathbf{E}[\frac{nX_2-{X_2}^2}{k-1}]
\end{align}

given $\mathbf{E}[{X_2}^2] = \mathbf{E}[{X_2}] = \frac{n}{k}$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] = \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}
\end{align}

So my answer differs to the solution on the matter of $\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2]$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] = \frac{n(n-1)}{k^2} \neq \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}
\end{align}
Whats wrong with my logic? Or maybe MIT is wrong.

Comment: You are probably ;) right but I don't see why $E[X_2^2]=E[X_2]$.

Comment: Your right it shouldn't be the same, I think I got confused with the expectation of just one dice roll squared. $E[{X_2}^2] = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ according to proof wiki. I'll try to work out the problem with this new finding.

Comment: Indeed, they are not equal. $X_2$ follows a binomial $B(n,1/k)$ distribution. Thus $V(X_2)=n.(k-1)/k^2=E(X_2^2)-E[X_2]^2$ and $E(X_2)=n/k$.

Comment: The formula you give for for $E[X_2^2]$ cannot be exact because it does not depend on parameter $k$.

Comment: Hey man thanks to your hints I managed to get the given solution, do you want to write it up so I can accept you. Alternatively I can write it up to save you time and post it, and you can copy it and post it. I'll be happy to do that. Whats the stackexchange way to do this?

Comment: Thanks. I am happy that it has helped you, that'all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it turns out MIT was right and I was wrong.

Thanks to the help from [JeanMarie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jeanmarie) I was able to come up with the following derivation.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[{X_2}^2] &= \mathrm{var}(\mathbf{E}[{X_2}^2]) + \mathbf{E}[X_2]^2 \\
\mathrm{var}(\mathbf{E}[{X_2}^2]) &= \frac{n(k-1)}{k^2} \\
\mathbf{E}[X_2]^2 &= \big(\frac{n}{k}\big)^2 \\
\mathbf{E}[{X_2}^2] &= \frac{n(k-1)}{k^2} + \frac{n^2}{k^2} \\
&= \frac{n^2+n(k-1)}{k^2}
\end{align}

Following from where my own solution left off, bunch of algebra.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[X_1X_2] &= \mathbf{E}[\frac{nX_2-{X_2}^2}{k-1}] \\
&= \frac{1}{k-1}\big(n \cdot \frac{n}{k} - \frac{n^2+n(k-1)}{k^2}\big) \\
&= \frac{1}{k-1} \big( \frac{n^2k}{k^2} - \frac{n^2}{k^2}\big) - \frac{n}{k^2} \\
&= \frac{n^2}{k^2} - \frac{n}{k^2} \\
&= \frac{n(n-1)}{k^2}
\end{align}

Which agrees with the MIT solution.